# Scala with keyword usage

Tags: scala

I found simple example:

```
class Post extends LongKeyedMapper[Post] with IdPK {
    def getSingleton = Post

    object title extends MappedText(this)
    object text extends MappedText(this)
    object date extends MappedDate(this)
}


object Post extends Post with LongKeyedMetaMapper[Post] {
    def getPosts(startAt: Int, count: Int) = {
        Post.findAll(OrderBy(Post.date, Descending), StartAt(startAt), MaxRows(count))
    }

    def getPostsCount = Post.count
}
```

What does it mean `with IdPK` ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

`with` means that the class is using a Trait via [mixin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin).

`Post` has the Trait `IdPK` (similar to a Java class can `implements` an Interface).

See also [A Tour of Scala: Mixin Class Composition](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/mixin-class-composition.html)

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about traits in scala.

Answer (score 23):

While this isn't a direct answer to the original question, it may be useful for future readers. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin#In_Scala):

*Scala allows to mix in a trait (creating an anonymous type) when creating a new instance of a class.*

This means that `with` is usable outside of the top line of a class definition. Example:

```
trait Swim {
  def swim = println("Swimming!")
}

class Person

val p1 = new Person  // A Person who can't swim
val p2 = new Person with Swim  // A Person who can swim
```

`p2` here has the method `swim` available to it, while `p1` does not. The *real* type of `p2` is an "anonymous" one, namely `Person with Swim`. In fact, `with` syntax can be used in any type signature:

```
def swimThemAll(ps: Seq[Person with Swim]): Unit = {
  ps.foreach(_.swim)
}
```

**EDIT (2016 Oct 12):**
We've discovered a quirk. The following won't compile:

```
 // each `x` has no swim method
 def swim(xs: Seq[_ >: Person with Swim]): Unit = {
   xs.foreach(_.swim)
 }
```

Meaning that in terms of lexical precedence, `with` binds eagerly. It's `_ >: (Person with Swim)`, not `(_ >: Person) with Swim`.

Comment: hey @fosskers, I'm looking for an answer online but didn't manage to find one, and in my search I ended up here - if I have `Seq[_ >: Person with Swim]`, does this mean "any supertype of type `Person with Swim`" or "any supertype of type `Person`, with `Swim` mixed in"? To be honest, neither makes too much sense and I never had the need to use it, but I found it in other code.