# Why is it possible to mutate immutable.SortedMap and immutable.TreeMap?

Tags: scala

Why is it possible to mutate `scala.collection.immutable.SortedMap` and `scala.collection.immutable.TreeMap`?

```
scala> import scala.collection.immutable.SortedMap
import scala.collection.immutable.SortedMap

scala> var sm = SortedMap(3 -> 'x', 1 -> 'x', 4 -> 'x')
sm: scala.collection.immutable.SortedMap[Int,Char] = Map(1 -> x, 3 -> x, 4 -> x)

scala> sm += (2 -> 'x')

scala> sm
res1: scala.collection.immutable.SortedMap[Int,Char] = Map(1 -> x, 2 -> x, 3 -> x, 4 -> x)
```

Also, I do not see in

http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.SortedMap

and

http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.TreeMap

a definition of `+=`, so how does it exist?

Comment: You're not the only person confused by this Scala behavior - http://bruceeckel.github.io/2014/12/30/operator-underloading-in-scala/

Answer (score 6):

I agree that the syntax makes it look like you are mutating the object, but in reality the `+=` operation is just syntactic sugar for an addition to the original (using the `+` operator) and then a reassignment (when the original variable is a `var`). So:

```
scala> import scala.collection.immutable.SortedMap
import scala.collection.immutable.SortedMap

scala> var sm = SortedMap(3 -> 'x', 1 -> 'x', 4 -> 'x')
sm: scala.collection.immutable.SortedMap[Int,Char] = Map(1 -> x, 3 -> x, 4 -> x)

scala> sm += (2 -> 'x')

scala> sm
res1: scala.collection.immutable.SortedMap[Int,Char] = Map(1 -> x, 2 -> x, 3 -> x, 4 -> x)
```

Is equivalent to:

```
scala> var sm2 = SortedMap(3 -> 'x', 1 -> 'x', 4 -> 'x')
sm2: scala.collection.immutable.SortedMap[Int,Char] = Map(1 -> x, 3 -> x, 4 -> x)

scala> sm2 = sm2 + (2 -> 'x')
sm2: scala.collection.immutable.SortedMap[Int,Char] = Map(1 -> x, 2 -> x, 3 -> x, 4 -> x)
```

You can see this by trying to use a val:

```
scala> val sm3 = SortedMap(3 -> 'x', 1 -> 'x', 4 -> 'x')
sm3: scala.collection.immutable.SortedMap[Int,Char] = Map(1 -> x, 3 -> x, 4 -> x)

scala> sm3 += (2 -> 'x')
<console>:10: error: value += is not a member of scala.collection.immutable.SortedMap[Int,Char]
              sm3 += (2 -> 'x')
```

For a comparison, look at this mutable map:

```
scala> val sm4 = scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int, Char](1 -> 'x')
sm4: scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int,Char] = Map(1 -> x)


scala> sm4.put(2, 'x')
res6: Option[Char] = None

scala> sm4
res7: scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int,Char] = Map(2 -> x, 1 -> x)
```

Here we were able to change the contents of a `val` map, something you can only do if the object is mutable.

Comment: Gotcha, I overlooked the fact that `sm` was defined as `var` - now it makes sense. Actually I thought that in Scala, syntax like `+=` has to be explicitly defined as a method, because I saw it for example in `mutable.Set` - why does this class have to define `+=`, `++=`, `-=`, `--=`? How does it work with the syntactic sugar feature? Also I was reading that instantiating `SortedMap` actually returns `TreeMap`, so why doesn't the command line explicitly present the created instance as `TreeMap` (it simply says `Map`) - and how can I verify what the actual concrete instance that I am getting is?

Comment: This has been asked and answered numerous times already. If `a += b` does not type-check, but `a = a + b` does, the compiler will re-write the former to the latter.

Comment: Thanks @JörgWMittag.

Comment: @rapt As for your other questions, they may be good posts on their own, but I am sure the `SortedMap` vs `TreeMap` difference has to do with the fact that `TreeMap` uses the `SortedMap` trait, see [docs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761534/scala-with-keyword-usage)

Comment: @rapt If this post answered your question please accept it

Answer (score 3):

The way immutable collections work is that operations which add, remove, or modify elements instead create a new collection on the heap.  So if there were multiple variables which held references to your `SortedMap`, the others besides the one you modified would still reference your original collection, and not the modified version.  (This is important, as one of the main benefits one hopes to get from immutable collections are safe multithreading and parallelization.)

Note that while I say "create a new collection", many of the elements may not need to be copied.  For efficiencies sake they will reference the same objects on the heap where possible.  This sharing is largely invisible to the user (other than the performance benefit) because as soon as you change one of these shared elements, the two collections will no longer reference the same element.  Scala's immutable collections are generally designed such that modifications can be accomplished while copying as little of the collection as possible.

Note also that this sort of modification to the collection referenced by `sm` was only possible because you declared `sm` as `var`, rather than `val`.  Since you're only "modifying" the collection by returning a new collection, the reference stored in your variable had to change. In contrast, mutable collections can be modified in place, so in that case you could change the collection referenced by `sm` even if `sm` was declared as `val`.

Regarding your question about where `sm +=` is defined, it's syntactic sugar for `sm = sm +`.  The expression `sm + (2 -> 'x')` returns a reference to the new collection that results from adding this element, and this reference is then assigned to `sm`.

Comment: You wrote "...as soon as you change one of these shared elements, the two collections will no longer reference the same element." -  how is it achieved...? and why would I want it to work this way?

Comment: @rapt By updating references (pointers), basically.  For example, suppose you have a binary tree where each node holds references to its children.  If you change a node on the left-hand side of the tree, you'll need to create a new top-level node that holds a reference to the new left-hand side, but it can hold a reference to the same right-hand side.  This spares you from having to copy the whole right hand side of the tree.  (And in fact there can also be subtrees on the left that don't need copying, since they don't reference the changed node.)

Comment: The point is that we'd like to have essentially the same semantics you would get from doing a deep copy (in the sense that any reference to the original collection still points to that same unmutated collection), but without the performance cost of doing a deep copy.

Comment: Some data structures are much more suitable to this sort of partial re-use than others.  I believe this is, for instance, why Scala implements `mutable.HashSet` using a hash table, but implements `immutable.HashSet` using a hash trie.